# How to convert the array's string value

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsarray

I have the array that is save following values:

```
globalarray_beacon: (
"(01000466)",
"(01000008)",
"(01000003)",
"(01000001)",
"(01000006)",
"(01000004)",
"(01000007)",
"(01000005)",
"(01000469)",
"(01000468)",
"(01000420)",
"(01000002)",
"(01000444)",
"(01000463)",
"(01000468)",
"(01000466)",
"(01000001)",
)
```

I want to convert this values into following:

```
globalarray_beacon: ( 
01000468,
01000004,
01000006,
01000420,
01000444,
01000466,
01000469,
01000003,
01000005,
01000008,
01000001,
01000007,
01000002
)
```

try1.

```
NSArray *items = [theString componentsSeparatedByString:@" " "];
```

try2.

```
 NSString *stringWithoutSpaces = [myString 
  stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"()" withString:@""];
```

try3.

```
  for (int i=0; i<array_lastname.count; i++) {


   [array_data addObject:[[array_lastname objectAtIndex:i] componentsSeparatedByString:@"()"]];

}
```

how to convert the array's value I have to tried many things. How's that possible to convert string value to data.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please add 'tried many things'?

Comment: @RonakChaniyara see this edit

Comment: How did you get `"(01000466)"` ? Could the issue be in the retrieval of that data instead, because, you can surely remove the parenthesis but the "real" fix could be before.

Comment: Hello @Larme this data fetch from sqlite and save this data in array.

Comment: And you save the data with parenthesis? Or could it be a "hard cast" on a NSArray object and using `description`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NSString` has a convenience method `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet` to do that

```
NSArray *globalarray_beacon = @[@"(01000466)", @"(01000008)", @"(01000003)", @"(01000001)", @"(01000006)", @"(01000004)", @"(01000007)", @"(01000005)", @"(01000469)", @"(01000468)", @"(01000420)", @"(01000002)", @"(01000444)", @"(01000463)", @"(01000468)", @"(01000466)", @"(01000001)"];
NSMutableArray *trimmedArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString * string in globalarray_beacon) {
    [trimmedArray addObject:[string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"()"]]];
}
NSLog(@"%@", trimmedArray);
```

Comment: thanks @vadian its worked thanks a lot you save my time.

Answer (score 1):

Try this below code

```
NSString *tempString = [[arrayOfStrings objectAtIndex:i] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""];
tempString = [tempString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];
[arrayOfConvertedStrings addObject:tempString];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
 NSMutableArray *arr =[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"(123)",@"(321)", nil];
    for (int i = 0; i<arr.count; i++) {
        NSString *str = [arr objectAtIndex:i];
        str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@"" ];
        str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@"" ];
        [arr replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:str];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"(12345)",@"(12345)", nil];
    NSMutableArray *obj = [NSMutableArray array];
    for(NSString *str in array){
        NSString *temp = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"(" withString:@""];
        temp = [temp stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@")" withString:@""];
        [obj addObject:temp];
    }
```

Comment: It is right but in swift , why someone down vote. hate these ppl who don't respect other atleast give reason to downvote.

Comment: @karthiyan I am on gmail.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for a category first, that'd help you out instantly, even if you don't want to spent resources to convert your entire array (for reasons).

---

it'd look like this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSString (MyTrimmedString)

- (NSString *)trimmed;

@end
```

and, of course, the essential implementation:

```
@implementation NSString (MyTrimmedString)

- (NSString *)trimmed {
    return [self stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"()"]];
}

@end
```

---

then you can directly apply it on strings, like e.g.:

```
NSString *_thingy = @"(01000466)".trimmed; // that will present "01000466"
```

or even on your array's items, like e.g.:

```
NSArray *_array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"(01000466)", @"(01000008)", @"(01000003)", @"(01000001)", @"(01000006)", nil];
NSString *_thingy = [_array firstObject].trimmed; // that will present "01000466"
```

---

from here, creating a new array (if necessary) is a piece of cake:

```
NSMutableArray *_newArray = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString * obj in _array) {
    [_newArray addObject:obj.trimmed];
}
```

which gives you an array with the trimmed elements, like e.g.:

```
// ( "01000466", "01000008", "01000003", "01000001", "01000006" )
```